# How to validate the textbox hours and minutes

Tags: silverlight, c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0

Using C#, visualstudio 2010, silverlight
2 textbox, 1 botton name called

textbox1, textbox2, button1

```
textbox1 - input allow only hours (HH)
textbox2 - input allow only minutes (mm)
```

button1_click event

i want to validate the textbox1, textbox2 with following condition

```
textbox1, allow only hours between 00 to 23
textbox2, allow only minutes between 00 to 59
```

How to write a code or function. Need code help

Comment: _redacted_ This is asp, oops. You can still look into [`NumericUpDown`](https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=NumericUpDown%20Control&referringTitle=Tutorials) control from AjaxControlToolkit.

Comment: Can't you just parse the textboxes for their input and check if their values are between the parameters?

Comment: Just hours between 0 and 12? What about times in the afternoon or evening?

Comment: @HansKesting: OP probably has a DropDownList for AM/PM.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying achieve

1. set the max lenght of text boxes to 2
2. wire the keydown of both the text boxes to a commonhandler and prevent the non numeric key press
3. On the Button click validate the ranges for both Hours and minutes. Following is the sample.

> public partial class MainPage : UserControl
>       {
>           public MainPage()
>           {
>               InitializeComponent();
>               txHour.MaxLength = 2;
>               txtMinutes.MaxLength = 2;
>               txHour.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(txt_KeyDown);
>               txtMinutes.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(txt_KeyDown);

```
    }
    private void txt_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Key < Key.D0 || e.Key > Key.D9)
        {
            if (e.Key < Key.NumPad0 || e.Key > Key.NumPad9)
            {
                if (e.Key != Key.Back && e.Key != Key.Shift && e.Key != Key.Tab)
                {
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
            }
        }

    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        bool isvalid = false;
        int x, y;

        if (int.TryParse(txHour.Text, out x) && int.TryParse(txtMinutes.Text, out y))
        {

            if (x >= 0 && x <= 23 && y >= 0 && y <= 59)
            {
                isvalid = true;
            }
        }

        if (!isvalid)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("InValidTime");
        }


    }

}
```

1. But if you want to restrict Ctr + V (paste) then you may need to create a new textbox class inheriting the textbox to acieve this.